# React i18n translate issue

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, translate

I am using i18n in my meteor/react app and encountered some problem.
In this case everything is working perfect:

```
import { translate, Trans } from 'react-i18next';
...
export class AddressVerificationForm extends React.Component {
...
{this.props.t('address.photos.format')}
...
export const AddressVerificationFormTranslated = translate('common')(AddressVerificationForm);
```

But in this case:

```
import { translate, Trans } from 'react-i18next';
...
export function UserInterface({data, onAdmin, isAdmin}: propTypes) {
...
{this.props.t('address.country')}
...
export const UserInterfaceTranslated = translate('common')(UserInterface);
```

I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 't' of undefined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first snippet you are extending the React class, but in the second snippet, `this` doesn't refer to your component, but to the function itself. As such, there are no props to read from. You need to add the argument `t` along with the other ones.

In other words, this should work:

```
export function UserInterface({data, onAdmin, isAdmin, t}: propTypes) {
...
{t('address.country')}
```